Using IRS2104 gate driver to drive BJT push pull stage
Among other things I am consider using an easily available IRS2104 gate driver to drive a BJT push pull stage described in this post to deal with the problems encountered:
Symmetric square wave duty cycle reduces with increase in frequency in push pull stage

Here's a brief on what's going on
Source: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/industry-articles/an-overview-of-driver-circuits-for-piezo-transducer-buzzers/
I need to switch 100 V so the transistors I'm using here and a pair of MJE40 and MJE50 NPN and PNP pair.
I intend to replace the first BJT that's accepting the signal with IRS2104 gate driver, but since I do not need bootstrapping, I am thinking of ditching the capacitor and related circuity as shown as in this example altogether and just using it to switch the 100 V necessary to drive the BJTs.

Instead I'm looking at the functional block diagram as shown below and I think doing the following will resolve my issue:

Connect Vb to 100 V power supply directly and tie Vs to ground.

HO goes to base of PNP and NPN.


Since HO goes between 100 V and 0, I think that should be enough to drive the push pull stage.

Source: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRS2104-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567633f727a1
Will this work as intended?

Why not use the MOSFET inverter directly? What are the BJTs offering here?

VS - VB is limited to 25V absolute maximum, so HO  will not go from 100V to 0 (at least not more than once).
HO also has the wrong phase to drive a PNP transistor.
Even if it did work (perhaps with two NPN transistors and a separate floating power supply or maybe bootstrap) it's quite possible the fixed 520ns dead time is inadequate to prevent fatal shoot-through with BJTs.

Do you know of any commonly available ICs that would be good to drive a push pull stage like mine?
